# PI Robot upper_base_link not showing in Rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!
I am having a minor issue in Rviz not displaying a link in Rviz. As you can see in the images the robot seems to be floating but in reality in my URDF files it is connected.
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

URDF:

```
<!-- * * * Link Definitions * * * -->

<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.0425" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.32 0.26 0.085"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan1">
            <color rgba="0 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="base_laser">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.025" length="0.07"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Black1">
            <color rgba="0.2 0.2 0.2 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="cpu_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.035" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.19 0.19 0.07"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan2">
            <color rgba="0 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
    </visual>   
</link>

<link name="upper_base_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.085" length="0.10"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Cyan3">
            <color rgba="0 0.5 0.5 0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="torso_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.12" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.24"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Yellow2">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="head_pan_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.0225" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.05 0.045 0.045"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Green1">
            <color rgba="0 1 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="head_tilt_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.02" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.038 0.04"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Green2">
            <color rgba="0.1 0.8 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="neck_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.021" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.05 0.042"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Green3">
            <color rgba="0.1 0.5 0.1 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="head_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.07 0.11"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Grey1">
            <color rgba="0.9 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>
    
<link name="antenna_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.035" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.002" length="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Grey3">
            <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0.8 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_shoulder_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.025 0.015 0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Green1">
            <color rgba="0 1 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="right_shoulder_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.025 0.015 0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Green1">
            <color rgba="0 1 0 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_shoulder_forward_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.05 0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue1">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>
    
<link name="right_shoulder_forward_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.05 0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue1">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_shoulder_up_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.05 0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="right_shoulder_up_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.05 0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_upper_arm_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0075" length="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Grey1">
            <color rgba="0.9 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="right_upper_arm_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0075" length="0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Grey1">
            <color rgba="0.9 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_elbow_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 1.57"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.035 0.035 0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="right_elbow_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 1.57"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.035 0.035 0.05"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_lower_arm_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0075" length="0.11"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Grey1">
            <color rgba="0.9 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="right_lower_arm_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.0075" length="0.11"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Grey1">
            <color rgba="0.9 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_wrist_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.05 0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="right_wrist_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.05 0.03"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Blue2">
            <color rgba="0 0 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="left_hand_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.01 0.06"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Grey1">
            <color rgba="0.7 0.7 0.7 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<link name="right_hand_link">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.03 0.01 0.06"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="Grey1">
            <color rgba="0.9 0.9 0.9 1.0"/>
        </material>
   </visual>
</link>

<!-- * * * Joint Definitions * * * -->

<joint name="cpu_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="cpu_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.025 0 0.085" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="base_laser_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_laser"/>
    <origin xyz="0.18 0 0.07" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="upper_base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="cpu_link"/>
    <child link="upper_base_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.07" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="torso_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="upper_base_link"/>
    <child link="torso_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.10" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit lower="-3.1416" upper="3.1416" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
</joint>

<joint name="head_pan_servo" type="fixed">
    <parent link="torso_link"/>
    <child link="head_pan_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.225" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="head_pan_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="head_pan_link"/>
    <child link="head_tilt_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.045" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit lower="-3.1416" upper="3.1416" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
</joint>

<joint name="head_tilt_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="head_tilt_link"/>
    <child link="neck_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.04" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
</joint>

<joint name="neck_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="neck_link"/>
    <child link="head_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.05 0 0.015" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="antenna_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="head_link"/>
    <child link="antenna_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 -0.025 0.065" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="left_shoulder_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="torso_link"/>
    <child link="left_shoulder_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0.055 0.165" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="right_shoulder_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="torso_link"/>
    <child link="right_shoulder_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 -0.055 0.165" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="left_shoulder_forward_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="left_shoulder_link"/>
    <child link="left_shoulder_forward_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0.025 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="right_shoulder_forward_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="right_shoulder_link"/>
    <child link="right_shoulder_forward_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 -0.025 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="left_shoulder_up_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="left_shoulder_forward_link"/>
    <child link="left_shoulder_up_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0.04 -0.01" rpy="0 -0.707 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="right_shoulder_up_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="right_shoulder_forward_link"/>
    <child link="right_shoulder_up_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 -0.04 -0.01" rpy="0 -0.707 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="left_upper_arm_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="left_shoulder_up_link"/>
    <child link="left_upper_arm_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="right_upper_arm_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="right_shoulder_up_link"/>
    <child link="right_upper_arm_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="left_elbow_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="left_upper_arm_link"/>
    <child link="left_elbow_link"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.005 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-3.146" upper="3.146" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="right_elbow_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="right_upper_arm_link"/>
    <child link="right_elbow_link"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.005 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-3.146" upper="3.146" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="left_lower_arm_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="left_elbow_link"/>
    <child link="left_lower_arm_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.08" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="right_lower_arm_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="right_elbow_link"/>
    <child link="right_lower_arm_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.08" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="left_wrist_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="left_lower_arm_link"/>
    <child link="left_wrist_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="right_wrist_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="right_lower_arm_link"/>
    <child link="right_wrist_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="left_hand_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="left_wrist_link"/>
    <child link="left_hand_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.055" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="right_hand_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="right_wrist_link"/>
    <child link="right_hand_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.055" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287040/pi-robot-upper_base_link-not-showing-in-rviz/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-30**:
Which element/link do you think should be there?

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-04-02**:
Should be upper_base_link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is the color

```
    <material name="Cyan3">
        <color rgba="0 0.5 0.5 0"/>
    </material>
```

The alpha value is set to 0, meaning transparent. Try

```
    <material name="Cyan3">
        <color rgba="0 0.5 0.5 1.0"/>
    </material>
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-04-03**:
How did i not see that lol Thanks to much!